# Pandas to_csv inside Python for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have two dataframes dfA & dfB. I need to use dfA's Date column to be the parameter for turncating the dfB and return the different new dataframe(s) dfC(s) and save them to csv one by one. I am using FOR loop to do this as blow but i got only ONE(the first) dfC and save to csv, it suppose to got more than that :

dfA:

```
index Date     Name
0     20221002 Peter
1     20221003 Mary
2     20221003 Ben
3     20221002 Mark
4     20221003 Jenny

dfA = dfA[['Date']].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
dfA['Date'] = pd.to_datatime(dfA['Date'])
dfA.set_index('Date',inplace=True, drop=False)
dfA = dfa[['Date']]

# dfA look like this after works above:
Date(index) 
             Date 
2022-10-02   2022-10-02 
2022-10-03   2022-10-03
```

dfB

```
Date(index)      
            Pay
2022-10-01  $500   
2022-10-01  $200
2022-10-02  $230
2022-10-03  $20
2022-10-04  $210
```

For loop:

```
for i in dfA['Date']: #pick date from dfA['Date'] one by one
    j = 0
    if i !='':
        dfC =  dfB(ascending=True).truncate( before = i)#using i(date of dfA) to truncate dfB 
        dfC.to_csv('E:\'dfC'+ str(j) +'.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig',index=False)#save new dataframe to csv
    j+=1
j+=1
```

I expected to got two csv fils because there are two Date(s) are not duplicated in dfA(20221002 & 20221003)BUT I ONLY GOT ONE

First dfC(truncate using 20221002)I only got this one:

```
Date(index)      
            Pay
2022-10-01  $500   
2022-10-01  $200
2022-10-02  $230
```

Second dfC(truncate using 20221003)this one didn't output to csv:

```
Date(index)      
            Pay
2022-10-01  $500   
2022-10-01  $200
2022-10-02  $230
2022-10-03  $20
```

Comment: This `'E:\'dfc'+...` does not do what you think.  I believe you meant `'E:\\dfc'+...`.  What you wrote is going to place those files in whatever the "current directory" for E: is, not into the root of E:.

Comment: Are you overwriting the file?

Comment: i am using the 'j' to be a part of the name of csv files....you guys means it didn't work?